# Proper setup of Vue.js methods to deal with Axios asynchronous request

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, axios

I have Vue.js app that fetch some complex data from API with Axios and then visualize this data.
My code looks similar to this:

```
{
  data: () => ({
    data: null,  // or Object, it doesn't matter now
    loading: false,
    errored: false,
    loadingMessage: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    loadData: function() {
      this.loading = true;
      this.loadingMessage = 'Fetching Data';
      axios.get('api/url/').then((response) => {
        this.data= response.data;  // or this.$set(this, 'data', response.data), it doesn't matter now
        this.loadingMessage = 'Process Data';
        this.processData();
      })
      .catch(function () {
        this.errored= true;
      })
      .then(function () {
        this.loading = false;
      })
    },
    processData: function() {
        // process data
    }
  }
}
```

So then I click on the button in template, this button calls `loadData()` function.
It works fine, but fetching data takes some time and processing also takes some time and Vue change template and variables only when axios request is finished. So I see only `Fetching Data` message but not `Process Data`.

How can I show the user at what stage of processing the data now?
Maybe I should call the `processData()` function in `watch methods`, but that seems overkill to me.

### Update

I ended up with `setTimeout()` wrap. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use `$nextTick()`, as [@joachim-bøggild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3870685/joachim-b%C3%B8ggild) advised me. I even tried to use `$forceUpdate()` to archieve this goal. But for some reason that was not clear to me, the effect I needed was not observed. The console showed that the value has changed. But on the screen and in Vue Devtools old results were shown until the request was completed.

So I decided to supplement the question with an example and started to create demo on JsFiddle. To show the rendering delay that I need, I used `setTimeout(() =>{ this.loading = false}, 1000)` and there were no problems at all.

I ported this approach to my code and everything worked perfectly. Until I tried to remove this `setTimeout()`. The problem arose again.

Therefore, in the end, I ended up on this code design:

```
...
      axios.get('api/url/').then((response) => {
        this.data= response.data;
        this.loadingMessage = 'Process Data';
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.processData();
          this.loading = false;
        }, 10);  // if this value less than 10 error still occurs
      })
      .catch(function () {
        this.errored= true;
      })
...
```

If someone understands why this behavior is happening, please complete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Vue has a function called `nextTick`, which is an asynchronous function that basically means "perform the following code after the next visual update". I usually use this method if I have visual updates like this to make.

I think the code in your example would look like this:

```
axios
  .get('api/url/')
  .then((response) => {
    this.data= response.data;
    this.loadingMessage = 'Process Data';
    return this.$nextTick();
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.processData();
  })
  .catch (etc ...
```

I am not completely sure. I usually work in webpack/babel-enabled environments, in which case I would just make the whole function `async` and write:

```
async function fn() {
  const response = await axios.get('api/url/');
  this.data = response.data;
  this.loadingMessage = 'Process Data';
  await this.$nextTick();
  this.processData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this what I need. I'll test your option in few hours and return.

Comment: Unfortunately, your approach didn`t help me.
I posted an answer that has a solution to my problem. But honestly, I do not quite understand how it works. If you have any ideas why this is possible, I will be glad if you explain to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about it here (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)

Can you try changing your function as follows:

```
loadData: function() {
  this.loading = true;
  this.loadingMessage = 'Fetching Data';
  axios.get('api/url/').then((response) => {
    this.data= response.data;  // or this.$set(this, 'data', response.data), it doesn't matter now
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.loadingMessage = 'Process Data';
      this.processData();
    })
  })
  .catch(function () {
    this.errored= true;
  })
  .then(function () {
    this.loading = false;
  })
},
```

Comment: Thank you, but somehow this doesn't work. I ended up with ```setTimeout()``` wrap.